# UILabel font is too small first time cell is shown

Tags: uitableview, uilabel

I'm resizing my UITableViewCells to adjust to their text size in heightForRowAtIndexPath:.  However, occasionally the font comes out sized for a smaller (44px) size.  This is fixed when the cell is hidden and shown again.

How can I force UILabel to only use the font size I give it?

[EDIT] By the way, I know about adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth, but it doesn't support multiline labels.  I also tried [cell setNeedsLayout] when the text is set.

[image: First time the cell is shown]
[image: Second time the cell is shown]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by setting the font size programmatically in cellForRowAtIndexPath:.  Feels a bit hackish, but it works.